# Scrolling a ul list in a div

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css

i have a div within which there is an `<ul>` with several items. the enclosing div has a css class attached to it for styling.

what i want to do is to be able to scroll the div when the items in the `<ul>` increases.

i tried to use jScrollPane but no luck. can someone please help how to scroll a div or ul?

Comment: add your code here or create a jsfiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/2VNyd/

```
<div style="height:100px;overflow-y:scroll">
    <ul>
        <li style="height:15px:">asd</li>
        <li style="height:15px:">as</li>
        <li style="height:15px:">asd</li>
        <li style="height:15px:">asd</li>
        <li style="height:15px:">asd</li>
        <li style="height:15px:">asd</li>
        <li style="height:15px:">asd</li>
        <li style="height:15px:">asd</li>
        <li style="height:15px:">asd</li>
        <li style="height:15px:">asd</li>

    </ul>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

set fixed height of the div.
set overflow to auto.

```
.divScroll
{
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

not that when height will more than 150 automatically a scroll bar will be visible over the div.

```
<div class='divScroll'>
    <ul>
        <li></li>
        ......
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the CSS, you can set a fixed height, and set the overflow to scroll.

```
ul.whateverclass (or ul#whateverid)
{height: px;   //desired height//
overflow-y: scroll;}  //use overflow-x for horizontal scroll, and overflow for both//
```

Should do the trick:)